# Google Maps for ios, Create a NSDictionary of markers in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, nsdictionary

In my app i create an array of objects called StoreInfo. the markers on the map are generated using the fields of the StoreInfo objects.
later i would like to generate an info window using additional data stored in StoreInfo's fields.
hence i need to create a dictionary between the markers and the info objects.

```
    storeMarkerMap = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

for(StoreInfo *info in storesArray){

            CLLocationCoordinate2D pos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(info.lat,info.lng);
            GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:pos];
            marker.title = info.name;
            marker.snippet = info.type;
            marker.icon =[self iconSelector: info];
            marker.map = mapView_;
            [storeMarkerMap setObject:info forKey:marker];
        }
```

...

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    CustomInfoWindow *infowindow =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    StoreInfo *info = [storeMarkerMap objectForKey:marker];


    infowindow.title.text = info.name;
    infowindow.description.text = info.address;
    infowindow.phone.text=info.phone;
    return infowindow;
}
```

This would not work since the marker object doesn't follow the following requiement:

> the Keys must implement the hash and isEqual

Comment: Is this code compile? This line shouldn't work [storeMarkerMap setObject:info marker];

Comment: thanks i've issued a fix

Comment: this doesn't seem what you WANT. you just need to associate 1 marker with 1 store info, no? (side note: this does compile but would crash -- but nvm. ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to use all your answers together to solve this problem.

1. I created a unique field of class StoreInfo
2. Assigned this unique data to each marker when created in the first loop
3. Created a dictonary that maps unique id's to StoreInfo object.
4. When i want to retrive the StoreInfo associated with a marker i look for the userData of the marker ( = StoreInfo unique identifier) in the dictionary

---

```
storesArray = [db StoresArray];

for(StoreInfo *info in storesArray){

    CLLocationCoordinate2D pos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(info.lat,info.lng);
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:pos];
    marker.title = info.name;
    marker.snippet = info.type;
    marker.icon =[self iconSelector: info];
    marker.userData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",info.storeId];
    [storeMarkerMap setObject:info forKey:marker.userData];
    marker.map = mapView_;

}


- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {
CustomInfoWindow *infowindow =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
 StoreInfo *info = [storeMarkerMap objectForKey:marker.userData];
infowindow.title.text = info.name;
infowindow.description.text = info.address;
infowindow.phone.text=info.phone;
return infowindow;}
```

Answer (score 5):

**easiest**: use the store as userData for the marker :)

==> no need to mess with an extra dict (IMHO cleanest too)

so:

```
for(StoreInfo *info in storesArray){
        CLLocationCoordinate2D pos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(info.lat,info.lng);
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:pos];
        marker.userData = @{@"store":info};
        ...
    }
```

...

```
    - (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {
        StoreInfo *info = marker.userData[@"store"];
                ...
    }
```

Comment: keeping it in a map is also easy. have unique IDs .. but this is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

This requirements simply says that if you want to use some object as a key for NSDictionary the object should implement NSCopying protocol and you should override two methods hash and isEqual.

// EXTENDED

I have never worked with that class but if it's still complaining that you must implement hash and iEqual and you want to use it as a key in your dictionary I would recommended you to create custom class which inherit from GMSMarker class and implement NSCoding and I would create those two methods. Or you can use something different as a key.

Comment: Can i override these methods for the GMSMarker or should i implement this other way?

Comment: I have never worked with that class but if it's still complaining that you must implement hash and iEqual and you want to use it as a key in your dictionary I would recommended you to create custom class which inherit from GMSMarker class and implement NSCoding and I would create those two methods. Or you can use something different as a key.

Comment: the answer in the comment only. I'd propose fixing the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a bit garbled, as is your code. You should provide more background about what you are trying to do, and on the third party frameworks you are using, so your readers can understand and help you without having to do a ton of research. I know a lot about Cocoa and objective C, but not the Google Maps iOS API. I don't have time to go research that API just to answer your  question.

Now, here's what I was able to figure out from your post:

You loop through an array of StoreInfo objets, creating a marker object for each.

Then you try to add your StoreInfo object to a storeMarkerMap dictionary, using the marker as the key. That line does not make sense.

In Cocoa and Cocoa touch, dictionary keys are almost always NSString objects.

I would expect you to add your GMSMarker object to the storeMarkerMap dictionary using an NSString key, like perhaps the title.

I haven't used the Google maps APIs before, so I don't know the classes you are using, but I would expect you to add your GMSMarker object to the storeMarkerMap dictionary using an NSString key, like perhaps the title.

Thus, I would think the line:

```
[storeMarkerMap setObject:info forKey:marker];
```

…should probably be something like:

```
[storeMarkerMap setObject: marker forKey: marker.title];
```

instead.

(That code would add each newly created marker object to the storeMarkerMap dictionary using it's title as a key.)

Comment: don't use localised Strings that might not even be unique as keys -- not in dicts, plists, database, view tags, anything

Comment: also and that is more relevant... I don't think this helps the op. (the way you have the storeMarkerMap is pointless) He wants to associate data with the store